# Asp.net , to_date Function

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I want to update record in oracle db. But it gives me error "date format picture ends before converting..." I uses to_date function. datatype of column is DATE.
Here is my query

```
             var updateddate = DateTime.Now;
              var testing=  this.hidvalue.Value;
             var idrow = id.Text;
            var anserrow = lblanswer.Text;
            var weightpwd = lblweighted.Text;
            var solvetimerow =lblsolvetime.Text;
            var updatedby = Session["Name"];
string queryDuppass = "Update ADU.QAT_DATA set Question='" + idrow + "',Answer='" + anserrow + "', Question_Weighted='" + weightpwd + "',  Resolve_Estimated_Time='" + solvetimerow + "', Updated_By='" + updatedby + "', Updated_Date= to_date('" + updateddate + "','mm-dd-yyyy hh12:mi:ss'" + ")" + " where ID='" + testing + "'";
```

Comment: If datatype is `DATE`, then you don't need to use `to_date`.

Comment: Make sure your updateddate  is mm-dd-yyyy, example 02-11-1985

Comment: When I remove to_date function it gives me the same error

Comment: "10/23/2017 11:35:19 PM" this is the debugger output when i used breakpoin.  which is in format of above given format

Comment: You should use `'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'`

Comment: when i remove to_date function it gives me error "not a valid month"

Comment: Yes it's working now. by inserting AM. Thanks Everyone

Comment: But why can't i update record with out using to_date function as column datatype is DATE.

Comment: You are converting `updateddate` to DATE using `to_date`.